# Create a complicated form of dictionary with try and except

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have been using list comprehension quite religiously throughout this project and finally I ran into a trouble where some elements do not have the range of index that is required.

Here is my code for better understanding:

```py
result_box_lst = [{
            "coordinates": box['boundingPoly']['normalizedVertices'], 
            "product": [{
                "product_name"  : product["product"]["name"],
                "product_uri"   : product["product"]["img_uri"],
                "price"         : product["product"]["product_price"],
###################### problematic area #############################################
                "product_label1": product["product"]["productLabels"][1]["value"],
                "product_label2": product["product"]["productLabels"][2]["value"],
                "product_label3": product["product"]["productLabels"][3]["value"],
######################################################################################
                "score"         : product["score"]
                } for product in box['results'] if product["score"] >  0.25]
        } for box in grouped_results]
```

Here, the problem is that sometimes `product["product"]["productLables"]` does not have multiple elements in the list so the list comprehension crashes with an `IndexOutofRange` exception. So I was thinking of catching it with try and except and googled it, but alas, list comprehensions can't have `try/except` within them.

Thus I started coding in the basic way of doing for loop and got stuck wondering how I can create the same structure of complicated dictionary/list using the basic form of for loop. So far, I build this:

```py
result_box_lst = []
product = []
        for box in grouped_results:
            for product in box['results']:
                if product["score"] >  0.25:
                    try:

                    products.append({
                        "product_name": product["product"]["name"],
                        "product_uri"   : product["product"]["img_uri"],
                        "price"         : product["product"]["product_price"],
                        "product_label1": product["product"]["productLabels"][1]["value"],
                        "product_label2": product["product"]["productLabels"][2]["value"],
                        "product_label3": product["product"]["productLabels"][3]["value"],
                        "score"         : product["score"]
                    })

                    except:
                    pass
```

However, I am quite confident that this will never achieve what I wish. Is there any way to make such complicated dictionary/list with this for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a very complex comprehension, so a for loop might end up being more readable and maintainable. But if your only issue is that sometimes your list indices are out of bounds, you can handle that with `if` / `else`:

```
"product_label2": product["product"]["productLabels"][2]["value"] if len(product["product"]["productLabels"]) > 2 else "",
"product_label3": product["product"]["productLabels"][3]["value"] if len(product["product"]["productLabels"]) > 3 else ""
```

Also, did you deliberately use indices `[1]` `[2]` `[3]` instead of `[0]` `[1]` `[2]`? Just checking...

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
for box in grouped_results:
    for product in box['results']:
        if product["score"] >  0.25:
            data = {
                "product_name": product["product"]["name"],
                "product_uri"   : product["product"]["img_uri"],
                "price"         : product["product"]["product_price"],
                "score"         : product["score"]
            }
            for i in range(1,4):
                if i < len(product["product"]["productLabels"]):
                    data['product_label{}'.format(i)] = product["product"]["productLabels"][i]["value"]
                else:
                    data['product_label{}'.format(i)] = "Some default value"
            products.append(data)
```

But do note that array starts with `0` so you might need to change a little bit depend on your case